# Dynamic Row and Column Creation using WPF and MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

Note: I'm using *MVVM Light Toolkit* and *MahApps.Metro*.

I've checked the answers but it doesn't seem like any of them relate to my question.

I have a Grid whose columns and header should be dynamically created. The number and value of columns is unknown to view, and the number of rows is unknown to view.

Columns, rows and data in the rows represent a Database Table. All data is present in the ViewModel.

I have an `ObservableCollection<ServerRow> ServerRows;` in my ViewModel.

Server Row object is a Model that looks like this:

```
    public class ServerRow : ObservableObject
    {
         private ObservableCollection<ServerColumn> _columns;

         public ObservableCollection<ServerColumn> Columns
         {
             get { return _columns; }
             set { Set(() => Columns, ref _columns, value); }
         }
     }
```

This is a `ServerColumn` class :

```
    public class ServerColumn : ObservableObject
    {
         private string _name;
         private string _type;
         private string _value;

         public string Name
         {
             get { return _name; }
             set { Set(() => Name, ref _name, value); }
         }

         public string Type
         {
             get { return _type; }
             set { Set(() => Type, ref _type, value); }
         }

         public string Value
         {
             get { return _value; }
             set { Set(() => Value, ref _value, value); }
         }
}
```

The Idea was to Bind DataGrid to `ObservableCollection<ServerRow> ServerRows;`, and then generate the Columns depending on the `ServerRow` object which has `ServerColumns` which in turn have `Name` (should be a header of the column), `Type` as the datatype of column data, and `Value` as the value which should be represented in every row/column.

My XAML is pretty simple (because it's not complete, and of course- not working)

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ServerRows}"/>
```

How do I write the XAML properly to achieve what I'm trying to do?

This is the result, which makes sense because Grid is trying to show a collection of objects inside a single Column and calling its `ToString()` method.

[image]

Comment: What output do you expect, i.e. how many columns do you want to display for each ServerRow? Where are these columns defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before too.

If you look at what is done here:

https://github.com/taori/WMPR/blob/0a81bc6a6a4c6fc36edc4cbc99f0cfa8a2b8871c/src/WMPR/WMPR.Client/ViewModels/Sections/ReportEvaluationViewModel.cs#L503

You provide the iteratable collection as `ObservableCollection<object>` when the underlying structure is actually of type DynamicGridCell, which uses a DynamicGridCellDescriptor which can be found at

DynamicGridCell:

```
public class DynamicGridCell : DynamicObject, ICustomTypeDescriptor, IDictionary<string, object>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    AttributeCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
    {
        return new AttributeCollection();
    }

    string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetClassName()
    {
        return nameof(DynamicGridCell);
    }

    string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetComponentName()
    {
        return null;
    }

    TypeConverter ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
    {
        return null;
    }

    EventDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return null;
    }

    PropertyDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return null;
    }

    object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents()
    {
        return null;
    }

    EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return null;
    }

    private PropertyDescriptor[] CreatePropertyDescriptors()
    {
        var result = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
        foreach (var pair in _values)
        {
            result.Add(new DynamicGridCellDescriptor(pair.Key));
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
        var result = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(CreatePropertyDescriptors());
        return result;
    }

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var result = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(CreatePropertyDescriptors());
        return result;
    }

    object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Add(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        _values.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Clear()
    {
        _values.Clear();
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        return _values.Contains(item);
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, object>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(item.Key))
        {
            _values.Remove(item.Key);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int Count => _values.Count;

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.IsReadOnly => false;

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return _values.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public void Add(string key, object value)
    {
        _values.Add(key, value);
    }

    bool IDictionary<string, object>.Remove(string key)
    {
        return _values.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out object value)
    {
        return _values.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get { return _values[key]; }
        set
        {
            if (_values.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _values[key] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                _values.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public ICollection<string> Keys => _values.Keys;
    public ICollection<object> Values => _values.Values;
}
```

DynamicGridCellDescriptor

```
public class DynamicGridCellDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        public DynamicGridCellDescriptor(string name) : base(name, null)
        {
        }

        public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            return ((DynamicGridCell) component)[Name];
        }

        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        {
            ((DynamicGridCell) component)[Name] = null;
        }

        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            ((DynamicGridCell) component)[Name] = value;
        }

        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override Type ComponentType => typeof(DynamicGridCell);
        public override bool IsReadOnly => false;
        public override Type PropertyType => typeof(object);
    }
```

Just make sure that the property you bind to is of type `ObservableCollection<object>` anyways - otherwise for me automatic grid column generation did not work.

Comment: I've tried looking at the code, but I'm not sure I understand what's happening.

You have a custom control called DynamicGridCell?
I don't understand how to use it. I already have bound an ObservableCollection, I can change it's access type to object.

Comment: it's not a custom control. Merely a custom structure allowing you to define an indefinite amount of columns. like cell["column1"] = "value1"; cell["column2"] = "value2";

Each indexer generates a column and will be rendered in your grid. Each cell object you create will turn into a row

Comment: Apologies for no answer, but had a lot of work during the weekend.
Yes, this was my answer! Thanks a lot!
However, i still don't understand how it works, and that is bugging me.
Any chance you could share some resources where you figured out how to get the solution? Would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Well to be honest i was inspecting a JsonObject if i recall correctly and wondered why i can just view it in the debugger like a table or something. So i looked up the source and built my class based on that. The thing which still puzzles me is that it does not work if the property you bind to is ObservableCollection<DynamicGridCell>. I'm a little puzzled there does not seem to be a built in class which works like that. I would imagine it is a scenario which is not that uncommon.

Comment: My thought exactly. It really does seem like not so uncommon thing, yet there's no support for it.
Regardless, thanks again for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some logical issues.

When you set the `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid` the bound collection will be used to create rows and if you don't change it the property `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to `true`. In this case the `DataGrid` will generate a column for each property in the bound collection and this is exactly what is happening in your sample. 
You bound an instance with a property 'Columns' and get a DataGrid column which is named 'Columns'. And you get as much rows as you have entries in this property displayed as '(Collection)' because `ServerColumn` inherits from `ObservableObject`.

You can set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and have to create the columns by your own; normally in xaml => hard coded.

If you really want to have dynamically generate the columns you have to write your own logic to create and bind the columns. I've done that once and it's pain in the ass if you want to have it generic. 
If you want a `DataGrid` with dynamic columns where the user can change values it's more tricky then a read only one.

One approach could be having a `ObservableCollection<string>` for the column names and another one `ObservableCollection` which stores your ViewModels for each row.

Comment: User won't change anything, Grid is there just to represent a result (it's read-only).
Also I don't shy away from some lines in code behind if it's gonna ease my job in designing this. But it has to stay dynamic.

Comment: Like I said: if you want to have it dynamic you have to add the columns by your own. For example in a Behavior or an AttachedProperty. You need the instance of the DataGrid to add the columns and their bindings. Edited my answer to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If both rows *and* columns really need to be dynamic, your best choice is to use two nested `ItemControl`s, the outer one representing rows, the inner one columns:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ColumnTemplateSelector}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This allows you to display different type of columns, by defining a template selector that might look somewhat similar to the following:

```
public class ColumnTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var column = item as ServerColumn;
        switch (column.Type)
        {
            case "Text":
                return TextTemplate;
            case "Number":
                return NumberTemplate;
            case "Image":
                return ImageTemplate;
        }
        // Fallback
        return TextTemplate;
    }

    public DataTemplate TextTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate NumberTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ImageTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

...based on each column's type, a different template would be referenced (all of these template obviously need to be defined somewhere and referenced as `StaticResource`. (This even allows easy creation of changeable (not read-only) grids.)

Note that, instead of the outer `ItemsControl`, you can of course use `ListView` or any other control that is derived from `ItemsControl`. Using a `ListView` might be useful if you need automatic scrolling, for example.